# SQL JOIN showing more results than it should show

Tags: sql

I have a simple problem that i am sure many can answer relatively easily. I have read several sites and previous questions on this subject and am still confused. I am a novice, but rapidly learning...

My two tables:

Table 1: Rank:

```
Rank firstinitial LastName Pos Team
51  A   Ellington   RB  ARI
78  M   Floyd   WR  ARI
85  L   Fitzgerald  WR  ARI
86  J   Brown   WR  ARI
107 D   Johnson RB  ARI
147 A   Cardinals   DST ARI
180 C   Palmer  QB  ARI
205 C   Johnson RB  ARI
223 C   Catanzaro   K   ARI
288 S   Taylor  RB  ARI
```

Table 2: Depth:

```
Team pos pos2 firstinitial lastname
ARI K   K1  C   Catanzaro
ARI QB  QB1 C   Palmer
ARI QB  QB2 D   Stanton
ARI QB  QB3 M   Barkley
ARI RB  RB1 C   Johnson
ARI RB  RB2 A   Ellington
ARI RB  RB3 D   Johnson
ARI RB  RB4 S   Taylor
ARI RB  RB5 K   Williams
ARI TE  TE1 D   Fells
ARI TE  TE2 J   Gresham
ARI TE  TE3 T   Niklas
ARI TE  TE4 G   Christian
ARI WR  WR1 L   Fitzgerald
ARI WR  WR2 M   Floyd
ARI WR  WR3 J   Brown
ARI WR  WR5 J   Nelson
ARI WR  WR6 B   Golden
```

SQL Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [r].[Rank]
      ,[d].[firstinitial] + '.' + [d].[LastName] as Fullname2
      ,[r].[Team]
      ,[r].[Bye]
      ,[r].[Pos]
      ,[d].[pos2]
FROM [football].[dbo].[rank] [r]
inner join [football].[dbo].[depth] [d] on [d].[firstinitial] + [d].[LastName] = [r].[firstinitial] + [r].[LastName]
where [d].[pos2] IS NOT NULL
and [r].[Pos] = [d].[pos]
order by [r].[Team], [d].[pos2]
```

Results:

```
Rank Fullname2 Team Bye Pos pos2
223 C.Catanzaro ARI 9   K   K1
180 C.Palmer    ARI 9   QB  QB1
205 C.Johnson   ARI 9   RB  RB1
107 D.Johnson   ARI 9   RB  RB2
51  A.Ellington ARI 9   RB  RB2
107 D.Johnson   ARI 9   RB  RB3
288 S.Taylor    ARI 9   RB  RB4
85  L.Fitzgerald ARI 9  WR  WR1
78  M.Floyd ARI 9   WR  WR2
78  M.Floyd ARI 9   WR  WR3
86  J.Brown ARI 9   WR  WR3
86  J.Brown ARI 9   WR  WR4
```

Question:

In this example, the 'RB2' position (under 'pos2') is shown twice in the results with two different individuals. However, if we look at the tables, we see 'A.Ellington' should be the only person listed under 'pos2' as the 'RB2'. I am not sure what i am missing with the join. The desired results would show unique rows with no duplicates.

Please help and explain the correct process. Thank you!

Comment: table d does not have firstinitial

Comment: Are you sure these queries work and produce the output as you have posted?

Comment: You don't have `Bye` column in your table definition. Also i have tried to get the output using your example an got the correct output check fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2eb8/3

Comment: I believe you are missing some core information in your question and you need to provide all the possible scenarios in your sample to help you better.

Comment: Thanks all. Table D now has firstinitial - that was a typo (copied from an older table). Yes, that code does output the results shown. What additional info do you need to assist? I can provide anything needed... Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what's specifically causing your problem, but I see things wrong. Your join should include the team and you are joining on concatenated strings; you should simply match column to column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [r].[Rank]
      ,[d].[firstinitial] + '.' + [d].[LastName] as Fullname2
      ,[r].[Team]
      ,[r].[Bye]
      ,[r].[Pos]
      ,[d].[pos2]
FROM [football].[dbo].[rank] [r]
inner join [football].[dbo].[depth] [d] on [r].[Team]=[d].[Team]
    AND [d].[firstinitial] = [r].[firstinitial]
    AND [d].[LastName] = [r].[LastName]
    AND [r].[Pos] = [d].[pos]
where [d].[pos2] IS NOT NULL
order by [r].[Team], [d].[pos2]
```

Comment: That was it. Joining on concatenated strings was the issue. One of those 'facepalm - why didn't i think to try that' moments :) Thank you very much!!